# First Letter separated and capitalized

Tags: python, python-3.x

First Letter separated and capitalized (python 3)

Let say we have this sentence:
"And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day."

Output:
A G S E T T H H M A B I W V G A T E A T  M W T S D

Actually I know how to do it, but don't know how to in 1 Line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = "And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day."
>>> ' '.join([i[0].upper() for i in s.split()])
'A G S E T T H H M A B I W V G A T E A T M W T S D'
```